# Running content script in only one chrome tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a chrome extension and I want this extension to work in only one open tab. For example, I want this extension to work only on google.com. But although I have two google.com addresses open, I want this extension to work on only one of them. So the content script will only work on one google.com tab. If I close the tab where the extension is running, I want this extension to work again in the google.com tab that I will open.

First of all, I find the tab id matching google by searching all open windows and tabs. If this tab id is removed, I want it to inject content.js in the tab id that matches google it will find again, but this code did not work.

Can you help me?

Background.js :

```js
var count = 0;
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (win) {
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function (tabs) {
      // Should output an array of tab objects to your dev console.
      for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if (tabs[i].url.match(/google/g) == "google" && tabs[i].status == "complete") {
          chrome.storage.sync.set({ indexTabId: tabs[i].id }, function () {
            return;
          });
        }else{
          chrome.storage.sync.set({ indexTabId: null }, function () {
            return;
          });
        }
      }
    });

  });
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ removed: false }, function () {
  });
  chrome.storage.sync.get('indexTabId', function (data) {
    // removed
    chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function (tabId, info) {
      chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function (tabremoved) {
        if (data.indexTabId == tabId) {
          
          chrome.storage.sync.set({ removed: true }, function () {
          });
          
        }
      });
    });
    chrome.storage.sync.get('removed', function (data) {
      if(data.removed){
        count = 0;
      }else{
        count = 1;
      }
    });
    if (data.indexTabId == tab.id && count < 1) {
      count++;
      console.log(tab.id);
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: 'content.js'
      });
    }
  
  });
});
```

Comment: Replace `tabs[i].url.match(/google/g) == "google"` with `tabs[i].url.includes('.google.')` or better yet switch to chrome.tabs.query instead of chrome.windows.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks but it works both ways.

Comment: The result of `match(/google/g)` will never be a string so your condition will never be true.